# Suggested questions should respect tags

Tags: feature-request, suggested-tags

This is a minor nitpick, but an annoying one. If I go to post a question

> System.IO broken and on fire

with the tag 'C#' I get suggestions for jquery questions with similar titles. Can the *Questions that may already have your answer* feature respect language tags, even if it doesn't go into the detail of matching the 'system.IO' tag?

Comment: There is a lot of low-hanging fruit to make the Ask Question page better.  They've been promising to fix it for many years already, didn't happen yet.  You'll have to use the tools at your disposal.  The ask page is not where to start researching a problem, it is where it ends.  That title is notable, it far too cute for its own good.  Google stumbles on it as well, even when you prefix "c#".  Keep it professional, show that you researched it, describe the real problem in the title, never emphasize an "it doesn't work" diagnostic.